# use multiple foreign_key in postgres

Tags: postgresql

i create table like this in postgres :

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.products
(
  id integer NOT NULL ,
   weight_p text  NOT NULL,
    price text ,
    company text ,
    type_p text ,
    size_p text ,
    model_p text,
    desc_2 text,
    desc_3 text,
    desc_1 text ,
    desc_4 text,
    limit_bandle text ,
    limit_capacity text ,
    CONSTRAINT proudcts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (type_p,model_p,company,weight_p,size_p)
)
```

and i want to use them as foreign_key in creating another table an i dont know how plz help

Comment: [Create Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html). See section starting *REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn ) ] [ MATCH matchtype ] [ ON DELETE referential_action ] ...*.

Comment: i dont get it this is my reference line    CONSTRAINT fk_product FOREIGN KEY (product) 
        REFERENCES public.products  [type_p,model_p,company,weight_p,size_p ]  MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION, could you explain more @AdrianKlaver

Comment: 1) Add code update to your question text as properly formatted code. 2) Also add the table definition for the table this constraint is declared on. 3) This `[type_p,model_p,company,weight_p,size_p ]` should be `(type_p,model_p,company,weight_p,size_p )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add matching columns and specify the FK separately:

```
create table test (
    id int primary key,
    fk_type_p text,
    fk_model_p text,
    fk_company text,
    fk_weight_p text,
    fk_size_p text, 
    foreign key (fk_type_p,fk_model_p,fk_company,fk_weight_p,fk_size_p)
        references public.products(type_p,model_p,company,weight_p,size_p)
);
```

Comment: thx it's work for me